# Java Sequential UUID

Tags: java, sql, uuid

I need to use UUID for the primary keys of some of my tables since they need to be globally unique across several client databases and some of the data will need to be merged back at some point.

Using a VARCHAR(36) column and java's version 4 UUID random generator solves the issue, but the problem with it is that the UUIDs aren't sequential so this will bring another issue with indexes and inserts especially on some large tables (1+ million rows).

I'm trying to generate a sequential yet random UUID, by replacing the Most Significant Bits from the UUID with the current timestamp (These bits already represent the timestamp anyway). I know there are solutions around the web to do this namely COMB UUID's, but strangely I couldn't find a Java implementation for it. I thought this would be a common problem.

I found an interesting implementation on C# here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database

A similar approach would do what I need, but I'm having a hard time converting this to Java, so if anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it. I think most of the problems is regarding big endian/little endian as I think Java will always use big endian and not the one from the native OS? Not really sure on how to deal with this.

My idea would basically be the same, generate a UUID using UUID.randomUUID() and then replace the MSB from the resulting id with System.currentTimeMillis(). One thing I'm not sure is about the amount of bytes I'd need for this because I think we can represent the current timestamp with 6 bytes and yet the timestamp portion of the UUID uses 7.5 bytes:

```
time_low               = 4*<hexOctet>
time_mid               = 2*<hexOctet>
time_high_and_version  = 2*<hexOctet> (1 byte for UUI algorithm version)
```

EDIT: I appreciate the answers so far, but please understand that my question is about implementing the above mentioned algorithm on Java and not to find another alternative for this. I understand there are several other possibilities, and the one that have been mentioned of including a client identifier is something I've used in the past, but I don't like that solution very much AND it wouldn't be applicable to this project because of mainly 2 things:
- This might work well when the amount of clients is known, which isn't the case this means I'd need to generate random ids for each client to make then as unique as possible this would mean 36 chars for the client id prefix and quite a few more for the sequential part this means primary keys of 50+ characters not a good idea.
- This won't solve the issue I'm trying to solve which is to have sequential primary keys, once you start inserting records from different clients into the same table the inserts are no longer sequential and you'll have a performance hit.

Comment: is your application server a single process or distributed?

Comment: UUID will only give "problems" if you use an index-organized table (ie it has a clustered index). If you want to avoid that, use a heap-organized table instead.

Comment: It's distributed. I don't have control over the database model and the primary key index is clustered.

Comment: I'm not certain what's unfocussed about this question, in order to have performace in large tables (at least for btree indices) you have to have sequential uuids.

I guess the only thing confusing to me is sequential across multiple clients, that might actually be hard, unless you do it in the DB. Still there's a deleted answer here that I'd like to see repubbed and modified

Answer (score 2):

You may be overthinking this.

You seem to have two requirements

1. Globally unique (among your databases) IDs.
2. Sequentially-generated IDs within each database.

I suggest that you assign each database a unique identifier, and then append a sequentially-generated value to get your identifier.

For example, if I have two databases A and B:

- A produces identifiers in this order: A-1, A-2, A-3, etc.
- B produces identifiers in this order: B-1, B-2, B-3, etc.

The identifiers are globally unique and sequential.

I would actually implement this identifier as two columns, one for the DB identifier (e.g., A or B) and the second for the sequence number (stored as an integral type).

You could even delay creation of DB identifiers until such time as you actually have to merge rows between two databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you manipulate the UUIDs by hand, no guarantee they're going to be unique - likely, but not guaranteed.  The more rows, the greater a chance of a hit.

Better design is to have a multipart primary key, something with a client code and an incrementing integer using a sequencee object.

If the databases operate independently and only need uniqueness when aggregated, such as in a data warehouse, then incorporate the client code only into the loading of the warehouse.

I'm sure you'll come back and say the data design is immutable and that you have to use UUIDs for the PK, but if you're not going to let them randomize themselves then it's the wrong design.

Comment: Even with UUID there's no guarantee they're going to be unique, that's a false question really, there's always chance for a duplicate to be generated. Randomization is still in place, I'm replacing the part that's generated based on the timestamp with another only sequential this time. True that the probability of a clash might increased, but it's still highly unlikely for that to happen and for this application usage that's perfectly acceptable, it's more likely for me to win the lottery twice in a row than for a duplicate id to be generated.

Comment: then it would seem your database design is compromised from the start, go to a two-part PK based on site and sequence and guarantee the uniqueness

Comment: But it wouldn't guarantee that all inserts would be sequential which is my primary question.